# Orion context broker log level

Tags: fiware-orion

is it possible to set logging level of orion?
Good will be to set some like WARN level.
Now is logging almost everything (like INFO level) and log file is growing so fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find useful the `--silent` CLI command (check [CLI parameteres list](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Command_line_options)).

> --silent. Suppress all log output except errors

You can pass it using the BROKER_EXTRA_OPS parameter if you run Orion as a service (more info in [this section of the manual](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#As_system_service)).